# Disable the logo, refresh and export icon in CrystalReports BI 4.1

Tags: crystal-reports, business-objects, business-objects-sdk

I am trying to disable the logo, refresh and export icon in CrystalReports.

To achieve this, I tried with the following options

In BOE.ear/BOE.war/WEB-INF/eclipse/plugins/webpath.CrystalReports/web/WEB-INF/web.xml 
added below entries

```
<context-param> 
<param-name>viewrpt.export</param-name> 
<param-value>false</param-value> 
<description>Set whether a export button will be shown</description> 
</context-param> 

<context-param> 
<param-name>viewrpt.logo</param-name> 
<param-value>false</param-value> 
<description>Set whether a logo will be shown</description> 
</context-param> 

<context-param> 
<param-name>viewrpt.refresh</param-name> 
<param-value>false</param-value> 
<description>Set whether a refresh button will be shown</description> 
</context-param>
```

But this is not working. Any expert advice would be helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, BI4 will use precompiled JSP files and will ignore any changes you make to the code.

If you want to make these **unsupported** changes, first locate the file `global.properties` in the folder `WEB-INF/internal` in the `BOE.war` archive. Look for the property `precompiled.jsp.files.use` and change it from `true` to `false`.

Next, redeploy the BOE webapp on your application server. Your changes should now be applied.

Comment: Hi Kristof, I have made the changes in the web.xml. So for xml file changes also we need to make the change in global.properties?

Comment: Yes, the `global.properties` file in the `internal` folder. Changes anywhere outside the `WEB-INF/Config/Custom` folder are not supported and require the change I described. You'll probably have to redo these changes every time you apply a support package or patch, as they will be discarded.

Comment: I have deployed after the changes. But still I can see the logo and the refresh buttons enabled. Any suggestion? Thanks.