# Disable Saplogo from OpenDocument in BI 4.1

Tags: crystal-reports, business-objects

I am moving from BO 3 to 4. I have a requirement to disable the saplogo that shows in the top right corner, when opening a report from opendocument.

Any suggestion will help me a lot.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean when using an OpenDocument link? Where exactly do you see the logo? Is it on the logon page or when showing the actual document? I've just tested this on a BI4.1 deployment, and I can't see any SAP logo when opening a document through OpenDocument. Perhaps you'd best add a screenshot to your post to clarify things.

Comment: Hi,

This I could see in CrystalViewer. When trying to access the report using the link [link]http://srvr:port/BOE/OpenDocument/opendoc/openDocument.jsp?iDocID=XXX&sIDType=CUID

We managed to disable logo when invoked in CrystalReportViewer directly [BI LaunchPad] by crystal_hide_online_resources_button=true

The logo appears at the top right corner of "SAP CRYSTAL REPORTS"

[link]http://www.sap.com/solution/sme/software/analytics/crystal-bi/index.html
[link]http://www.businessobjects.com/ipl/default.asp?destination=ViewerLogoLink&product=crystalreports&version=14%2E0

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29767344/disable-the-logo-refresh-and-export-icon-in-crystalreports-bi-4-1/29767811#29767811)

Comment: Hi, 
Yes both are disabled but in crystal reports. When the same report I am opening through opendocument it is showing up.
Thanks